# dissimulate vs dissemble

Tags: meaning

I've compared these words in a few contexts; there is a difference between them, but I can't make it explicit. What do you think it is, or know it to be?

(*I know these words are very close, and in actual use it might not matter. I'm asking to satisfy my own curiosity.*)

**Dissimulation**

From Wikipedia:

> Dissimulation is a form of deception in which one conceals the truth. Dissimulation differs from simulation, in which one exhibits false information. "Dissimulation, in the negative; when a man lets fall signs and arguments, that he is not, that he is... Simulation, in the affirmative; when a man industriously and expressly feigns and pretends to be, that he is not." In the animal kingdom a predator giving the impression that it is harmless is an example of dissimulation, such as the leaf fish. An animal that is typically prey giving the impression that it is dangerous is an example of simulation, such as the frill-necked lizard.

Definition from AHD.

> To disguise (one's intentions, for example) under a feigned appearance. See Synonyms at

From Vocabulary.com

> The noun dissimulation describes the act of faking your true feelings. Your dissimulation of happiness might fool strangers but your close friends can tell it's all an act.
>   The word dissimulation implies that the wool is being pulled over someone's eyes, or they're being fooled or tricked by someone's deceit. The origin of dissimulation is the Latin dissimulationem, which means "a disguising or concealment." Don't confuse dissimulation with dissimilation, which describes the act of making something different or less similar.

In context:

> - In war, practice dissimulation, and you will succeed.
> - I lack the cunning and the dissimulation,” she says, “necessary for a normal affair.
> - Uncertainty, fear, dissimulation and layerings of identity permeate the novel.

Wordnet: says dissimulation is a type of *falsification* and a type of *misrepresentation*

**Dissemble**

From AHD

> 1) To disguise or conceal behind a false appearance.
>
> 2) To make a false show of; feign
>
> 1) To disguise or conceal one's real nature, motives, or feelings behind a false appearance.

From Vocabulary.com

> To dissemble is to hide under a false appearance, to deceive. "When confronted about their human rights record, the Chinese government typically dissembles."
>   Dissemble is a little more complicated than a straight lie or denial. When you dissemble, you disguise your true intentions or feelings behind a false appearance. To dissemble is to pretend that you don't know something, to pretend that you think one way when you act another way. "My boyfriend was dissembling the whole time. He was a married father of two."

In Context

> - Or, worse, he’s giving them the idea that it’s OK to dissemble this way with your own kids.
> - Why is the government trying so hard to muddy and dissemble even this modest data?
> - Senna painted himself as the wronged man, but in seeking to justify the crash he dissembled.
>     -He didn't dissemble; the gist was "we do because we can".

Wordnet says dissemble is a type of *belie* and a type of *misrepresent*.

Comment: Can you summarize what a dictionary says?

Comment: Very close in meaning... Can't find significant differences between them.

Comment: Do you have any examples where you might feel there is some subtle difference? Maybe you could share them with the rest of us, along with your own impressions. At the same time, would you share the definitions (and sources) that you found in the dictionary?

Comment: I cannot up vote this because of the mouse-over on the up vote. It doesn't show research effort. Clearly you've done some research, now is the time to show it.

Comment: @DavidM updated

Comment: @Mitch updated.

Comment: @Jim --updated.

Comment: Much better +1!

Comment: Is the second 'dissimulate' a freudian slip?

Comment: @Mitch thanks for pointing that out. I'll return the favor:A Freudian slip denotes such a mistake as the one you mentioned, except it conveys that the speaker revealed something about their psyche. E.g. I saw two politicians debating the price of gas on CSPAN. One of them, who had recently acquired a reputation for patronizing hookers, stood up and boldly asked the speaker, "Mr.Speaker, is the Prime Minister aware of the sky rocketing price of ass in this country?" The PM replied, "Modulating such prices isn't in our mandate. But Freudian slips aside, we've already moved to reduce gas prices."

Comment: A freudian slip doesn't need to be sexual (though it often is). What I find interesting about this is that dissimulate is the older word and 'dissemble' seems to be originally a portmanteau or malapropism, but over time is a perfectly acceptable word.

Comment: @Mitch no it doesn't need to be, but it should reveal something about the person's intentions or disposition ( a source outside the speech). I wouldn't call a mistake a Freudian slip. Did you see something Freudian in that mistake?

Comment: Sorry if this is too much. Your question was about how these two words are different, and the mislabeling makes it look like you assumed they are the same (had the hidden intention that they should be the same). Or one could just say it was a trivial mistake.

Comment: *the mislabeling makes it look like you assumed they are the same*, Ha. I hadn't inferred that from your comment, but it's funny. Maybe it was a Freudian slip then.

Answer (score 2):

They are effectively synonyms. I see them listed as such in each other's definitions.

Both are derived from the Latin dissimulare. (To hide/conceal.)

**Dissemble** seems to have derived after a trip through old French from a combination of semblance and dissimule.

**Dissimulate** comes mostly unscathed from Latin.

These derivations are from the Google definitions of both words.

Comment: Foot note: Google has no definitions, it merely shows definitions from other dictionary websites.

Answer (score 2):

Dissimulate is to pretend to be different. More active/deliberate.

Dissemble is to fail to seem what you really are. Could be by omission.

Simulo in Latin means to pretend. Semblance in English is to do with appearing or seeming. There is a subtle difference.

Answer (score 1):

My take is that **dissimulate** is more concealing by omission - just not saying or avoiding questions on the topic.  **Dissemble** is somewhat more active and comes closer to outright lying.

Comment: I had thought that, too. But, I cannot seem to support it with a dictionary.

Comment: Why would you trust some dumb book over a guy on the Internet?  You crazy??

Comment: Because if I sit on the book, I can see over the edge of the table. If I sit on the guy on the internet … well, then we're talking a whole different type of website.

Comment: It might get more views that ELL though.

Comment: @Oldcat updated

Comment: @Oldcat yeah you made the same comment I put in my notes on the two words. Dissemble seems more active.

Answer (score 0):

All major dictionaries show them as synonyms. Only the example sentences and detailed meaning from OED got me to the following conclusion:-

Dissimulate: you feign something (that you're not)...Now that they have power, they no longer need to dissimulate

Dissemble: you hide something (that you are)...How many furtive inclinations avowed by the eye, though dissembled by the lips!