# A person who pretends to dislike a particular subject when in actuality they do like it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the English phrase used for when a person pretends not to like something, but in actuality they do. I wasn't sure if it is a French phrase that has been adopted into the English language.

Comment: This could just descend into a rehash of [dissimulate vs dissemble: difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157349/dissimulate-vs-dissemble) etc. 'The lady doth protest too much' is often used hereabouts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth While the answers there answer this question, it is not a duplicate at all - if you propose closing this one, on what grounds would you do so?

Comment: @Joachim 'What is the English phrase [/word, accepted tags] used for when a person pretends not to like **something**, but in actuality they do?' is a far broader question, with many precedents on ELU (see 'feign' / 'duplicity' etc) than ' ... A person who pretends to dislike a particular subject when in actuality they do like it'. A year has only produced two answers twisting the title question (_inanimate 'subject'_). I've not CV-d as yet (the question would close at once). I was hoping rather to forestall the usual ballpark repeats. // Grounds? Anti-mediocrity; anti-bloat; searchability.

Answer (score 0):

> If someone **plays hard to get**, they pretend not to be interested in another person or in what someone is trying to persuade them to do.

*There was never a suggestion of brinkmanship or playing hard to get.*

[Collins]

Answer (score 0):

*demure*: affectedly modest, reserved, or serious : COY

This brings us to:

*coy*: marked by cute, coquettish, or artful playfulness

Feel free to further research "coquettish" if you like, which has the French sound you may have been looking for, but may have a bit of a racy overtone.  These definitions are from merriam-webster.com.